# Build error with pods only for test target

Tags: ios, cocoapods

What I did :

- Tried to build project

What happened :

- It failed with "Error:The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation."
- The libPods.a is not generated

I have the latest cocoapods installed, and this is my podfile :

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

inhibit_all_warnings!
platform :ios, '7.0'

target :MyProjectTests, :exclusive => true do
    pod 'OCMock'
end
```

I have seen similar issues reported at CocaPods project on github, but nothing seems to work.

I don't need any pods for my main project, I'd just like to use `OCMock` for testing.

Comment: So, just run 'pod install'.

Comment: Yeah, been there done that. A couple of times. No luck. I even removed the  `*.xcworkspace` so it would get generated again. No luck.

Answer (score 0):

You should check that the **Manifest.lock** file is identical to **Podfile.lock**.
These files should be the same when a `pod install` command is executed.
If not, you should check if someone that is collaborating on your GIT project is changing the **Podfile.lock** (as it is usually under version control).

Answer (score -1):

Yo have to add the Test target to the Podfile between the main target:

```
target :mainTarget do
    link_with "MainTarget"
    //Added pods...
    target :tests do
        link_with "Tests"
    end
end
```

Comment: I already had it : `target :MyProjectTests, :exclusive => true do
    pod 'OCMock'
end`

Comment: Do you use any pod in the main target?

Comment: Nope, the podfile in the question was everything I had. As far as I remember I ended up adding some dummy pod to mitigate the issue.